# Is there a way to specify alternate packages outside of the .gwt.xml structure?

Tags: java, gwt, package

It doesn't look like the GWT documentation indicates this is possible and I've not figured out a way to do it so I suspect it is not but was wondering if anyone has figured out a way.

If my .gwt.xml file is located in com.foo.bar and I have a class in com.foo.bat is there a way to reference it via the <source> element in my .gwt.xml file?

I guess I could just move the .gwt.xml file up to some common base package...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either move the module definition file to a common base package, or (assuming `com.foo.bat` contains a GWT module) use an `<inherits name="com.foo.bat.Bat" />` tag. But no, you can't reference a package outside your module's scope as a `source`.

Comment: No that's wrong!! you can reference a source from outside!! by using relative path like <source path="../Bat"/>

Comment: @AdelBoutros according to the documentation, only source code that is 1) a child of the module's package; and 2) contains valid GWT source code; can be compiled.

Comment: "Note that this directory MUST be a sub directory of the directory that contains the .gwt.xml file! If you need to include another directory, see Including other modules." Refer to the documentation (specifically the "Finding files" section): http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/PathsHandlingFAQ